# Submit form to another page with a PUT Http request C#

Tags: c#, forms, asynchronous

I'm fairly new to C# and I'm trying to accomplish the following:

The end user has a switch button on a page where he can activate a service.This switch submits a form with data, that is sent asyncronous to another page where this same page needs to do a PUT request to activate the service.

Depending on what is returned, it will show a sucess or an error message in the same page where the user can activate the service.

There are two things new to me with Http requests in C#:

- How do I make the request on the page load, as in, the form is submitted to this page and it will make the request right away.
- How to retrieve the response back to the activation page?

So far this is my C# code on the page that needs to make the request.(The form is already submitting to this page):

```
public class FormValues
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string SubId { get; set; }
}

private static async Task<string> ServiceActivation()
{
    var user = User.GetUser();
    var valuesFromForm = new FormValues
    {
        Id = Dynamicweb.Context.Current.Request.Form["id"],
        SubId = Dynamicweb.Context.Current.Request.Form["subId"]
    };
    string requestUri = $"https://somedomain/api/{valuesFromForm.Id}/activate-service/{valuesFromForm.SubId}";
    var httpClient = new HttpClient();
    
    string _ContentType = "application/json";
    httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue(_ContentType));
    httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", $"Bearer {user.Token()}");
    var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(valuesFromForm);
    var httpContent = new StringContent(json);
    var response = await httpClient.PutAsync(requestUri, httpContent);

    response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
    var content = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
    
    return content;
}
```

In the Razor view:

```
@{
    @ServiceActivation()
}
```

Comment: Avoid `async void` except on events (where you have to). Change that to `async Task`, or more likely `async Task<JsonResult>` so you can return the JSON to the page.

Comment: To call this from your page, you'll need to use JavaScript and do two things, both of which you'll find lots of information for online: 1) ["javascript run code on load"](https://www.google.com/search?q=javascript+run+code+on+load) and 2) ["javascript make HTTP call and use JSON result"](https://www.google.com/search?q=javascript+make+HTTP+call+and+use+JSON+result)

Comment: @GabrielLuci thanks for your answer. We wanted to avoid using Javascript and were looking for ways to just do the Http PUT call in C#, retrieve the response on this page (page2) and depending on the result, show a success or error message on page1. Is it not possible?

Comment: You can, as long as you're comfortable with with the page not loading for the user until that PUT call is done (since it will delay the response from the server). In that case, you would put this code in the controller action for that page, then pass the data to the view to use.

Comment: By the way, the user doesn't go to the page2. The call is made to page2 which is where the Http request is processed, the user always stays in page1...it's like updating a part of the page but in this case, update the api resource with the PUT and do some kind of action on the client side so that the user knows the service is active or not.

Comment: It seems the request is returning "System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[System.Web.Mvc.JsonResult"
Shoot, it's difficult when you first start on something new :/, hopefuly it gets easier after this feature is completed.

Comment: I'm really not sure why it's returning a type. Am I not sending anything in the body of the request?

Comment: Any help? Still getting the type which I'm really not sure why I'm not getting the response?

Comment: It sounds like the return type is still `Task<string>`. Change the return type to `Task<JsonResult>`. Also, don't use `.Result`. Your method is `async`, so use `await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync()`.